# why must display be initialized when setting palette?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to manually create and save a color-indexed image (palette) as a PNG file, using pygame :

```
# create the bitmap
res = pygame.Surface((src.width, src.height), depth=8)

# create the palette
res.set_palette([pygame.Color((0, 0, 0, 0)), ...])

pygame.image.save(res, "test.png")
```

But I get :

> ```
> error: cannot set palette without pygame.display initialized
> ```

on the `set_palette` line.

Of course, it isn't difficult to initialize some dummy display, but I don't see why it should be the case. Nothing is displayed, and nothing seems display dependant in my code...

Also, it's totally useless to initialize pygame or display when you manipulate 32 bits Surfaces. What's the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the pygame source says so :)

But I couldn’t find any reason it was necessary, so I recently removed that check in https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/3259.

So this will not be the case in the next pygame release.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you could make the ```pygame.image.save``` function saves indexed png (currently it converts to 24bpp before saving) it'd be marvellous !

Comment: You’re really going to like the next pygame version, it’s already done: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/3028

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, because you create a surface no alpha channel (no `SRCALPHA` flag), but set an alpha channel with 0. Set a color without alpha channel:

<s>`res.set_palette([pygame.Color((0, 0, 0, 0)), ...])`</s>

```py
res.set_palette([pygame.Color((0, 0, 0)), ...])
```

A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is somehow associated with the display and is created in a format that best suits the display surface. You need to initialize Pygame with [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) or initialize at least the display module with [`pygame.display.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init).

Minimal working example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.display.init()
res = pygame.Surface((1, 1), depth=8)

# create the palette
res.set_palette([pygame.Color((0, 0, 0))])
```

Comment: I don't think so. I can perfectly manipulate surface without initializing the display or even pygame, I do this all the time with RGB32 images.

Comment: Yes I tried it. I simplified a bit for the sake of clarity but can post the original code if you want (the 32bits RGBA palette is deduced from a 9 bits BGR palette).
AFAIK, you can't use SRCALPHA with a 8 bpp surface ```(ValueError: no standard masks exist for given bitdepth with alpha)```

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Also, deleting the alpha component of the color doesn't solve the problem (and AFAIK, in the PNG specifications, indexed colors can have alpha channel)

Comment: @T.Tournesol I'm not rude but I get angry when I write an answer an somebody just doesn't read it. I don't know why, but I know how to fix it. To get the answer you need to red the source. Pygame is open source. https://github.com/pygame/pygame

Comment: Thanks. Pygame source is really difficult to read (I tried). I hoped someone would know. Sorry to have misinterpred you, and thanks for your time.